# Powershell - Getting and organising Active Directory groups of machine

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been trying to use the code below to get the list of AD groups that a target machine is in, but I am having some difficuly.

```
Get-AdComputer -Identity $hostname -property "MemberOf"
```

When I execute the code, I'm returned with this.

```
DistinguishedName : CN=$hostname,OU=test,OU=test,OU=test All Workstations,DC=te
                st,DC=test,DC=com
DNSHostName       : $hostname    Enabled           : True
MemberOf          : {CN=Flash_Player_Adobe_11.1.102_LCL,OU=test All Softw
                    are Groups,DC=test,DC=test,DC=test, CN=Adobe Acrobat X P
                    rofessional 10,OU=test All Software Groups,DC=test,DC=test,D
                    C=co.uk, CN=Silverlight_Microsoft_4.0.60.0_LCL,OU=test
                All Software Groups,DC=test,DC=test,DC=test}
Name              : %hostname    ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : 5cf00026-c91a-422e-8a3e-7ee546456717f
SamAccountName    : Test
SID               : f-1-5-21-18934363546-5655752-5353453-564535
UserPrincipalName :
```

Is there a way I can just have memberOf returned (the list of AD agroups attached to the machine and ordered in a list with just the group name listsed. For example just:

```
Silverlight_Microsoft_4.0.60.0_LCL
Adobe Acrobat XP Professional
```

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract group names:

```
(Get-ADComputer -Identity $hostname -Property MemberOf).MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you possibly help me with this please? I'm trying to get the outputted group names and put them into a DataGridView form but all I keep getting is numbers that are outputted to the DatagridView. function Get-AD { $active_d = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $current_hostname.text -Property MemberOf).MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1' $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList $array.AddRange($active_d) $current_output.DataSource = $array $current_output.refresh() } I'm using the above at the moment but it doesnt work

Comment: Also, could you briefly explain -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1'
please?

Comment: The regex captures anything between CN= and the next comma, ([^,]+) means any character that is not a comma. The capture is replacing the whole string.

Comment: Try this: $groups =  (Get-ADComputer -Identity $current_hostname.text -Property MemberOf).MemberOf -replace '^CN=([^,]+),OU=.+$','$1'; ; $dgv = New-Object Windows.Forms.DataGridView; $dgv.Columns.Add("Groups","Groups"); $groups | foreach { $null= $dgv1.Rows.Add($_) }

Comment: @ShayLevy thanks for this RegEx script, helped me out a bunch with something I was researching.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Get-AdComputer -Identity $hostname -property "MemberOf" | select -expand memberOf
```

Edit after comment:

try this I can't test it now

```
Get-AdComputer -Identity $hostname -property "MemberOf" | select -expand memberOf | % { ($_.split(','))[0].replace('CN=','')}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but how would you suggest I go about filtering the results so that only the app name is displayed?

Comment: Try my edit, but it possible have some bug, I can't test now.

Answer (score 1):

Orrin,

Don't forget your friends dsquery and dsget they work great with powershell as well.

You do a dsquery and then pipeline it right into  dsget -memberof with powershell and if need be trim with a foreach-object{$_trimstart(" ")}

Play with it and let us know what you use.

dc